# accessing data from Database

Tags: android

I am connecting oracle database through OJDBC.RAR. when i try to list out all the data from the database it show only the data which contains in the first column. the remaining data are not visible.  pls give me a solution

My Code:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver()); 
Connection conn; 
ResultSet rs; 
Statement stmt; 
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, user, passwd); 
stmt = conn.createStatement(); //getting values from DBS 
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM isroot"); 
rs.next(); 
id = rs.getString(1); 
name=rs.getString(2); 
genre=rs.getString(5);
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code, and the place where it goes wrong? That would be easier for us to help ;-). Also, have you tried debug messages with the contents of the variables?

Comment: How is this question related to android?

Comment: I am connecting oracle DB to android application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 it show only the data which contains in the first column
```

You have to iterate your ResultSet Object to get all the values.

Comment: How?? is it possible to iterate ResultSet object.. can you explain me briefly